# Filtering a string of unwanted chars in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, validation, filter

I am looping through hundreds of data entries, most of them valid according to my rules but there are some special characters or unwanted whitespace that must be filtered before the entry is used.

I only want `=` and `,` characters to be allowed along with digits and letters. No other special characters. There can be single white spaces but ONLY following a `,` to separate data.

I am calling a filter method inside a loop:

```
private String filterText(String textToBeFiltered) {
    String filteredText = null;

    // Remove all chars apart from = and , with whitespace only allowed
    // after the ,

    return filteredText;
}
```

I am completely new to regex but have been trawling tutorials and would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks!

Frank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `replaceAll` method as:

```
input = input.replaceAll("[^=,\\da-zA-Z\\s]|(?<!,)\\s","");
```

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/7jVQn)

The regex used is: `[^=,\\da-zA-Z\\s]|(?<!,)\\s` which means:

- replace any character other than `=`,
  `,` or a any digit or any letter or
  any non-space with `""`, effectively
  deleting it.
- Also delete any whitespace but only
  if it is not preceded by a `,`

Comment: @codadict: That does not work on real data. It fails on U+A0, which is in a **great deal** of text data — certainly it’s more than 95% of what I process. Your pattern also fails on 0x85, amongst several other common whitespace code points. Plus pretending those are all there is for letters is a naïve façade that nobody believes any more. Tschüβ!